# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line 0:undefined:-1

Tags: sql, join, hive, hiveql, non-equi-join

If anyone  would know  what the issue here is please ?
I am running this in Hive

```
 select * from a left join b
 on a.id=b.id and a.date between b.start_dte and b.end_dte
```

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line
> 0:undefined:-1 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN
> 'end_dte'

Answer (score 2):

Hive does not support non-equi joins.

Try to move a.date between b.start_dte and b.end_dte to the WHERE clause:

```
 select * from a left join b on a.id=b.id 
  where (a.date between b.start_dte and b.end_dte) or b.id is null
```

`or b.id is null` is to allow not joined records (left join)

Comment: Good finding bro...

Comment: thanks  but  seems like this  "or b.id is null" does not make any difference. I tried with where (a.date between b.start_dte and b.end_dte) and then where (a.date between b.start_dte and b.end_dte) or b.id is null and i am getting the same result

Comment: @tom it can be. inner join can produce the same result as left join if all records joined